# Newbie: Hadoop IIS Logs - Reasonable approach?

Tags: hadoop, iis, logging

I am a totaly beginner at the topic hadoop - so sorry if this is a stupid question.
My fictional scenario is, that I have several webserver (IIS) with several log locations. I want to centralize this log files and based on the data I want to analyze the health of the applications and the webservers.

Since the eco system of hadoop overs a variety of tools I am not sure if my solution is a valid one.

So I thought that I move the log files to hdfs, create an external table on the directory and an internal table and copy the data via hive (insert into ...select from) from the external table to internal table (with some filtering because of the comment lines beginning with #)
When the data  is stored within the internal table I delete the previous moved files from hdfs.

Technical it works, I tried it already - but is this is reasonable aproach?
And if yes - how would I automatize this steps  since now I did all the stuff manually via Ambari.

THanks for your input

BW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine approach.

Outside of setting up the Hive table ahead of time, what's the left to automate?

You want to run things on a schedule? Use Oozie, Luigi, Airflow, or Azkaban.

Ingesting logs from other Windows servers because you have a highly available web service? Use Puppet, for example, to configure your log collections agents (not Hadoop related)

Note, if it's only log file collection that you care about, I would probably have used Elasticsearch instead of Hadoop to store data, Filebeat to continuously watch log files, Logstash to apply per-message level filtering, and Kibana to do visualizations. If combining Elasticsearch for fast indexing/searching and Hadoop for archival, you can insert Kafka between the log message ingestion and message writers/consumers